# Converting an analog controller into a digital controller... Theory

Tags: dsp, controller, digital-control

I have created a stable PI s domain controller for my system. When I go to digitize it in PSIM by adding a ZOH and a delay block and by converting the PI controller into the z domain using backward Euler, the system obviously does not behave as expected. My question is how can I redesign this controller without using software. In essence what am I trying to correct in my new digital controller and how can I calculate it on paper?

Comment: How does it not behave as expected? Is your sample time << all time constants?

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house or on-line technical encyclopaedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. This is short summary that expects mountains of effort from other people in return. Please edit your question to show your own work, conclusions and own findings in considerable detail. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to share your design, in both \$s\$ and \$z\$ domain, and tell us *how* it is not behaving as expected.

Comment: **1** Why do you want to re design without using software ? It gets tedious quickly. **2** please share the details of your problem such as TF of the plant, the s-domain controller TF, the z-domain TF after conversion, relvenat screen shots, (stable) response of the system with s-domain controller, (unstable?) response with z-domain controller etc. **3** "*...the system obviously does not behave as expected*" What is the expectation, what is the actual result ? Please use the [edit] link below the question to add the details.